# shoot ball from middle of the screen Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Hi im trying to create a sphere and launch it in the direction im looking from the middle of the screen.
however im currently launching from the middle but always in the same direction and height.
tanx for any help.

```
     #pragma strict
         private var globe:GameObject;
              var globeMaterial:Material;
              private var shootIndex:boolean;

               function Start () {

}

function Update () {



if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
if (shootIndex==false){
globe=GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
globe.renderer.material=globeMaterial;
globe.AddComponent(Light);

globe.light.color=Color.blue;
globe.AddComponent(Rigidbody);

//globe.transform.position=Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
globe.transform.position=Camera.main.transform.position;
globe.transform.localScale=Vector3(0.5,0.5,0.5);


globe.rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward*1000);

shootIndex=true;

}
else if (shootIndex==true){
Destroy(globe);
shootIndex=false;
}

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is that Vector3.forward is always the Vector (0,0,1) as in one step towards the z coordinate(in this analogy y is upwards and x is right) as can be seen here:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector3-forward.html

Two solutions to this are:

1.) Add the Force in the direction your camera is pointing:

```
globe.rigidbody.AddForce(Camera.main.transform.forward * 1000);
```

You dont need "AddRelativeForce" here as your Globe isnt rotated in any way. so "AddForce" and "AddRelativeForce" have the same effect.

2.) Or  change the rotation of the sphere and then send the sphere forwards (relative to its own rotation):

```
globe.transform.rotation = Camera.main.transform.rotation;
globe.rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward * 1000);
```

Comment: so simple. ive been way off. trying with LookAt and rays. works like a charm